# Specify order of sequence with paste and rep functions

Tags: r, paste, rep

I'm trying to reverse-engineer the following code

```
paste("a", rep(1:4, each=4), 1:4, sep="")`
```

which gives the following result:

```
[1] "a11" "a12" "a13" "a14" "a21" "a22" "a23" "a24" "a31" "a32" "a33" "a34" "a41" "a42" "a43" "a44"
```

For reference, this code is from the Examples section of the LTRE{popbio} help file.

For my data, I need to repeat the following sequence 14 times: "a11 a12 a21 a22". When I try to modify the original code such that

```
paste("a", rep(1:2, each=14), 1:2, sep="")
```

I instead get

```
[1] "a11" "a12" "a11" "a12" "a11" "a12" "a11" "a12" "a11" "a12" "a11" "a12" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a21" "a22" "a21" "a22" "a21" "a22" "a21" "a22" "a21" "a22" "a21" "a22"`.
```

Technically these are the correct combos, but I need the sequence to be "a11, a12, a21, a22", "a11, a12, a21, a22", etc., not repeating "a11 a12" 7 times before switching to "a21 a22" 7 times. This seems like it should be simple but after trying all kinds of code modifications, I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rep` with both `each` and `times` argument

```
paste0("a", rep(1:2,times = 7, each = 2), 1:2)

#[1] "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11"
#[14] "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12"
#[27] "a21" "a22"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `paste` with `replicate`:

```
paste(replicate(14, "a11 a12 a21 a22"), collapse = " ")

[1] "a11 a12 a21 a22 a11 a12 a21 a22 a11 a12 a21 a22 a11 a12 a21 a22 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
rep(paste0("a", rep(1:2, each = 2), 1:2), 7)
#[1] "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12"
#[23] "a21" "a22" "a11" "a12" "a21" "a22"
```